# Add, edit or delete the features in a page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a subscription page consist of 3 cards, in which on selecting each card a button is enabled. This button is used to edit or add items to the page. when i click a card the button is enabled. so when i click the edit button i need to pop up with an alert box to edit the content in that card. please help.. Thank you

html code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ObsAuthService } from '../../services/obs_auth.services';
import { JobsearchPage } from '../jobsearch/jobsearch';
import { ConnectpayPage } from '../connectpay/connectpay';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-jobsub',
    templateUrl: 'jobsub.html',
    providers: [ObsAuthService]
})


export class JobsubPage {

     public category: string = "CLASSIC";
     public subscription: string = "PREMIUM";
     public option: string ="";
    //  public cardClicked: boolean = false;
     isenabled:boolean=false;
     editItem: any;
    //  public price: string ="";
    //  public p1: string = "₹100";
    //  public p2: string = "₹200";

    constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: ObsAuthService,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
        public navParams: NavParams) { }

    selectChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

//redirect to job search page
    public free_pay(){
        this.nav.push(JobsearchPage);
    }

//proceed to payment page
    public classic_pay(){

        this.nav.push(ConnectpayPage, {option: this.category});
    }

//proceed to payment page
    public premium_pay(){
        this.nav.push(ConnectpayPage, {option: this.subscription});
    }

//to enable the edit button
    public onCardClick(){
        //  this.cardClicked = !this.cardClicked;
        this.isenabled=true;
        this.editItem()
    }

    // public add_page(){

    // }
}
```

```css
page-jobsub{

.sentnc{
    color: grey;
    padding: 40px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.card-md {
    
    // width: calc(25% - 20px);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    // background: rgb(192, 179, 167);
}
.cost{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.titles{
    color: crimson;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.add_buttn{
    // width: 15%;
    // background-color: red;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    // text-decoration-color: white;
   width: 10%;
    
}
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>SUBSCRIPTION</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button [disabled]="!isenabled" class="add_buttn" (click)="add_page()">Add/Edit</button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-label class="sentnc">Take your desired plan to get access to our content easily</ion-label>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col2>
            <ion-card  (click)="onCardClick()">
                    <!-- <div *ngIf="cardClicked"></div> -->
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title class="titles">
                        FREE
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <p>1 MONTH FREE</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="cost">₹0</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>
                        <button (click)="free_pay()" ion-button color="dark" round>Choose plan</button>
                    </p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col2>
            <ion-card (click)="onCardClick()">
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title class="titles">
                        CLASSIC
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <p>6 MONTHS PLAN</p>
                    <p><del>₹150</del></p>
                    <p class="cost">₹100<sub>/month</sub></p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>
                        <button (click)="classic_pay()" ion-button color="dark" round>Choose plan</button>
                    </p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
            <ion-card (click)="onCardClick()">
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title class="titles">
                        PREMIUM
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <p>1 YEAR PLAN</p>
                    <p><del>₹250</del></p>
                    <p class="cost">₹200<sub>/month</sub></p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>
                        <button (click)="premium_pay()" ion-button color="dark" round>Choose plan</button>
                    </p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What's the problem? have you tried the alert but it does not work? do not know which component to use? Not sure how to pass data from the component to the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try  [ionic modal](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-modals/).

**Step**

1. Create modal page and add it in your module file.
2. On edit click open model and pass parameter value you want to edit.
3. Assign parameter to modal page input.
4. update Value in database